# Structuring Monitoring-Frontend with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, python, json, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I'm building a monitoring/statistic tool. The current infrastructure looks like following:

- Collector-Backend: Receives queries (JSON-objects) from the frontend, fetches and stores them in a cache. Finally it notifies frontend over a message queue.
- Frontend-Server: Handles subscriptions on the 'live'-views, pushes the data received from the backend to the user via WebSockets. (Also contains some user-management etc.)
- Frontend itself: Some JavaScript-Spaghetti-Code which render the data using jQuery-Flot-Graphs. There are a couple of graphs per environment which are displayed on the same page. A graph is a set of measurments.

An, what I call, environment is a (set of) system(s) which contains different measurments. Therefore each environment contains following views:

- a 'live'-view which displays the measurements of the last 2 hours (updated every minute).
- a statistic-view on which different pre-defined graphs can be selected over an arbitrary time (same queries as the live-views, just another view)
- some special reports like the yesterdays statistics.

An environment contains following variables:

```
{
  name: 'FooEnvironment',
  description: 'Foo Environment, <insert buzzwords here>',
  baseTable: 'foobar', # Which table in the backend contains the corresponding data
  target: 'barTarget', # The responsible target (backend-plugin)
}
```

The graphs are defined as a set of measurements (as a JSON-Object) and is defined like 
this:

```
 {
    name: 'FooProtocol Traffic', # Graphs display name
    size: 'full' # only matters for some CSS-transformations
    interval: X  # Which delta each tuple differs from the other
    start-date: "DATE",
    end-date: "DATE",
    axes: {
            "y1": { label: 'Foo/t', data: [['MEASURMENT1', 'AGGREGATION'], ['MEASURMENT2', 'AGGREGATION']] },
            "y2": { label: 'Bar/sec', data: [['MEASURMENT_ON_Y2', 'AGGREGATION']] }
    }
  }
```

I want to be able to manage those environments on my frontend (Adding/remove environments and add/remove graphs to them).

How would you modeling this using MVC (backbone.js)?

Please report me if I have to provide some more information :-)

Comment: Without narrowing down your question to the actual problem that you are facing, I doubt you would be able to get any good answer at all. May be you can tell us what part of your application design that you have the problem with? Provide us some code or some thought on how you think you would do it and ask for how you can improve is a much better question than literally asking how to **structure** an application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try having an `Environment` model and a `Graph` model.

The Environment model would have a `Graphs` property, which is a collection of `Graph` models.

A user's subscriptions could be a collection of `Environment`s that are being monitored.

There would be at least three views - one for holding the representation of a graph, one for holding the representation of an environment, and one for holding the collection of environments.

As you've mentioned adding/removing graphs and environments, there's a little more detail required.

For example, you'd need a list of available environments for the user to subscribe to, and under each environment subscribed to, a list of available graphs for that environment.

I know the answer is rambling and vague, but without further detail of what data is on hand, it's the  best I can do.